# Using Node Modules in Simple Project

Tags: npm

I have a very simple web project and I'm using npm init to create the package.json file for the project. My project structure is below:

```
ProjectFolder
--app /this is the folder for js files
--css
--scss
--lib /this is for files like jQuery
--index.html
```

When adding a node package, it will create a node_modules folder like this:

```
ProjectFolder
--node_modules
--app /this is the folder for js files
--css
--scss
--lib /this is for files like jQuery
--index.html
```

Let's say I add jquery through npm install and make it a dependency. Is it good practice to link to the jquery file in node_modules from my index.html or move the jquery file to my lib folder?

Is there a way to move the jquery file to my lib folder when installing?

I don't want to move the node_modules folder to the server and want to know the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json is essentially your link. It contains a list of the packages you are dependent on and their versions. If you install something using npm install it has to be a published npm package on an npm repository somewhere (either public or private). It downloads a zipped version of the npm package and unzips it into node_modules. Anything in there is automatically then available to your app. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess I'm asking in my html file is it good practice to link to the package like.

<script src="node_modules/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

or move the package to my own lib folder to keep the project lighter when I upload it to the server and link to it like this:

<script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

If this is the case is there a command or a script I can write that will do that for me?

Comment: Being honest I don't think it really matters too much. I'm not sure what you mean by script. All you want to do is reference the jquery. Is it absolutely necessary to reference it in your HTML ? Would just using it in your javascript alone (and thus being automatically accessible from node_modules) be sufficient ?